# Alternate Color in ListView C# (.Net 3.5)?

Tags: c#, listview, background-color

I'm gonna set an alternate color to my ListView rows.
I saw [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750769%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) but I'm using .Net Framework 3.5 SP1 , so I can't use it.
I've used the following code , but it has problem with ListView Sorting

```
ListViewItem newListViewItem = new ListViewItem(
    new string[] { item.name.ToString(), 
                   item.code.ToString() });
newListViewItem.BackColor = new Color(240,240,240);
newListViewItem.UseItemStyleForSubItems = true;
newListViewItem.Font = new Font("Tahoma", 9);
listView1.Items.Add(newListViewItem);
```

Could you please guide me how I can do it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is quite unclear from your snippet, but I'll guess you want alternating colors.  Even numbered items colored one way, odd numbered colored another way.  Yes, very effective as a reading guide when you have a large number of columns in the view.

And yes, that's going to get mucked up when you sort the items.  Right after sorting, you'll need a simple for loop that changes the BackColor property.

```
    private static void recolorListItems(ListView lv) {
        for (int ix = 0; ix < lv.Items.Count; ++ix) {
            var item = lv.Items[ix];
            item.BackColor = (ix % 2 == 0) ? Color.Beige : Color.White;
        }
    }
```

Call this after sorting.  Or after filling the ListView.  I suck at colors, please pick your own.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a easy way to do it -> [Alternate background](http://live.mscommunity.net/blogs/borissevo/archive/2008/10/21/wpf-trick-1-alternate-background-colors-for-listview-rows.aspx)

Comment: The link is for WPF, I wanna it in WinForms.