# C# WEb App Listview formatting

Tags: c#, asp.net

Building a web app here and I would like to be able to alternate my listeview rows. Can someone give me some sample code to achieve this? The 3 standard ones in VS2010 sucks and I'd like to be able to give it something that goes along with the scheme of my webapp. Row 1= blue, 2=gray, 3=blue, etc. Something to that effect.

Thanks

Comment: This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006071/alternate-color-in-listview-c-net-3-5/4006200#4006200 could be a similar situation but I think it's for WinForms.

Comment: WinForm ListView (System.Windows.Forms.ListView) is not similiar to System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListView).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the colors in your templates:

**Edited To Add**
I would imagine the header is built in the LayoutTemplate, so you can bold them there (see the code I added).  You'll probably want to use CSS - define the various styles you need in a separate CSS file as classes, and assign the classes where needed to save excess typing.

```
<asp:ListView id="ListView1" runat="server">
  <LayoutTemplate>
      <table>
          <tr>
              <td style="font-weight:bold;">header</td>
              <td style="font-weight:bold;">header</td>
          </tr>
          <asp:PlaceHolder id="itemPlaceHolder" runat="server" />
      </table>
  </LayoutTemplate>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <tr style="background-color:blue;">
        <td></td>
    </tr>
  </ItemTemplate>
  <AlternatingItemTemplate>
     <tr style="background-color:gray;">
         <td></td>
     </tr>
  </AlternatingItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

I've abbreviated the code considerably, but it should get you going where you want.

Comment: I believe he wants three alternating colors. Is that possible using this approach?

Comment: OP's question:  `Row 1= blue, 2=gray, 3=blue, etc. Something to that effect.`  Looks like alternating with only 2 colors.  I think you'd have to get more creative to use more than 2.

Comment: What abou the header? Where could I change that to say bold and underlined if I wanted too?