# How to change ListView cell's backcolor using c# windows form?

Tags: c#, windows, forms, winforms, listview

i want to change my ListView cell's Backcolor as the images look like. In the Image, there 1 cell is white and another is blue. So i wanted to make this type ListView.

[image]

Please any one solve this problem for me..

Thanks

Comment: this is actually not that difficult.. do you have any code that you have tried on your own..? if not do a google search here is a previous post that can help get you started..  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006071/alternate-color-in-listview-c-sharp-net-3-5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the backcolor for each item of your listview as simple as:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (i % 2 == 0)
                listView1.Items[i].BackColor = Color.Blue; 
            else
                listView1.Items[i].BackColor = Color.White; 
        }
```

You can also check [ListView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on MSDN for more information about this control

Comment: Its not working.. I wants this when the form loads, listview will be colored as that image have.

Comment: Sorry. My mistake. Its working.. Thanks sir..:)